# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component - memory leak?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect

I have tried using `mounted = useRef()` and `let mounted.current = true` at the beginning of my `useEffect` and `return () => mounted.current = false` but I'm still getting this error message:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in NameDetails (at TitleRow.js:114)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at TitleRow.js:113)
    in titleRow (at TodayTitleList.js:154)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at VirtualizedList.js:2015)
    in VirtualizedListCellContextProvider (at VirtualizedList.js:2030)
    in CellRenderer (at VirtualizedList.js:807)
    in RCTScrollContentView (at ScrollView.js:1107)
    in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1213)
    in ScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1264)
    in ScrollView (at VirtualizedList.js:1250)
    in VirtualizedListContextProvider (at VirtualizedList.js:1080)
    in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:620)
    in FlatList (at TodayTitleList.js:149)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (at SafeAreaView.js:51)
    in SafeAreaView (at TodayTitleList.js:136)
```

Looking at the stack trace, I am hazarding a guess that the error is at the `NameDetails` file and it involves the `useEffect` in there. Is this the case?

The following is my code:

```
const NameDetails = ({ title }) => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('#000');

  useEffect(() => {
    //let mounted = true; 
    const getColor = async (id) => {
      const chosenColor = await getColorFortitle(id);
      setColor(chosenColor);
    //return () => { mounted = false };
    };

    getColor(title.id);
  });

  return (
    <View>
        ...
    </View>
  );
};

export default NameDetails;
```

More information: this error occurs when I log out and try to log in again and it only happens some of the time.

Comment: hello, So what is your problem? you want to only bug fix? or another else?

Comment: I want to fix the bug yes but also understand why setting a boolean mount isn't correcting the problem.

Comment: can It's possible using state?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: you can get the value on state. And then use it. how about?

Comment: @Glisten tried but still get the warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const NameDetails = ({ title }) => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('#000');

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true; 
    
    const getColor = async (id) => {
      const chosenColor = await getColorFortitle(id);
      mounted && setColor(chosenColor);
    };

    getColor(title.id);

    return () => { mounted = false };
  }, [title.id]);

  return (
    <View>
        ...
    </View>
  );
};
```

A more desirable approach:

```
const NameDetails = ({ title }) => {
  const isMounted = React.useRef(true);

  React.useEffect(() => () => (isMounted.current = false), []);
  
  const [color, setColor] = useState('#000');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getColor = async (id) => {
      const chosenColor = await getColorFortitle(id);
      isMounted.current && setColor(chosenColor);
    };

    getColor(title.id);
  }, [title.id]);

  return (
    <View>
        ...
    </View>
  );
};
```

Or, if you're not sure what's going on there, you can try to use my library with generator-based asynchronous hooks where you don't have to worry about unmounting:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useAsyncEffect } from "use-async-effect2";

const NameDetails = ({ title }) => {     
  const [color, setColor] = useState('#000');

  useAsyncEffect(function*(){
      const chosenColor = yield getColorFortitle(title.id);
      setColor(chosenColor);
  }, [title.id]);

  return (
    <View>
        ...
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: why would a useEffect call without dependency be a more desirable approach? It will be called unnecessarily on every render.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial it's just a copy/paste issue- it's missing in the author's source code. Of course, we should always pass dependencies to hooks. "more desirable" == define the isMounted variable with useRef, since we can reuse it for all hooks used inside the component including `useCallback`.

Comment: isMounted.current && setColor(chosenColor); <- that was the missing line that fixed it for me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `useEffect` **everytime** you component re-renders:
Add an [empty dependency to `useEffect` to run only on first render](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects)

```
const mounted = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => mounted.current = true, []);


useEffect(() => {
    const getColor = async (id) => {
     const chosenColor = await getColorFortitle(id);
     setColor(chosenColor);
    }

    if(mounted.current)
      getColor(title.id);

    return () => { mounted.current = false };
}, []);
```

Comment: I can't use `await getColor(title.id);` because the useEffect isn't async?

Comment: yes you cannot. my bad. edited answer now see

Comment: check now, i forgot to add condition for mounting

Comment: It doesn't work, I still get the same warning.

Comment: Yes, I included the `if(mounted.current)`

Comment: well, it should not. Can you provide a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-pine-7hc05) link to reproduce your example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230683/discussion-between-jaeleeso-and-shivam-jha).

Answer (score 0):

Please check my code
I hope it will be help you.

```
const NameDetails = ({ title }) => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('#000');
  const [mounted, setMount] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => { 
    const getColor = async (id) => {
      const chosenColor = await getColorFortitle(id);
      setColor(chosenColor);
      return () => { setMount = false };
    };

    getColor(title.id);
  });

  return (
    <View>
        ...
    </View>
  );
};

export default NameDetails;
```

I only use the one state. So you can change the value using the state.
Run on your code.

Comment: What did  `const [mounted, setMount] = useState(true);` even do?

Comment: Also, you should not be using `useState` here. See [Is there something like instance variables?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)

Comment: Ok, can you tell me about title?